# Error: Compile Error: Missing '<EOF>' at 'Public' at line 12 column 5

Tags: apex

```
trigger ContactRelationshipMasterTrigger on Contact_Relationship__c(before update)  {     
  if(trigger.isBefore)     {    
  if(trigger.isUpdate)         {          
    //call the handler for the before update trigger event       
    updateCROwnerName ConRelUpd = New updateCROwnerName();          
    ConRelUpd.updateContactRelationshipNameByOwner(trigger.New);    
  }   

   } 
     } 
  //Class 
    Public Class updateCROwnerName {
   public void updateAccountRelationshipNameByOwner(list<Contact_Relationship__c> cont_Rel)     {   
   map<Id,Id> map_Id_Own = new map<id,id>();      
   map<Id,string> map_id_Name = new map<id,string>();       
   set<id> Idset = new set<id>(); 
for(Contact_Relationship__c List_recs:cont_Rel)         {           
   Idset.add(List_recs.Ownerid);      
     }     
   list<user> u=[select id,Name from user where id in:Idset];  
   for(user list_users:u)         {    
   map_id_Name.put(list_users.Id,list_users.Name);  
      }        
   if(u!=null && u.size()>0) {     
   for(Contact_Relationship__c List_recs:cont_Rel)             {            
   if (List_recs.Ownerid!=null)                 {                         
   List_recs.Name = map_id_Name.get(List_recs.Ownerid);
       }    
         }   
           } 
             }  
               }
```

Comment: Hi new user, welcome to SFSE, pelase take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familair with the forum. As is, it is unclear what you are asking, or what you have tried to make your code work. please [edit] your post accordingly. thanks

Comment: I've taken some liberties in formatting your code for you. Generally speaking, being consistent with indentation is pretty important if you want other people to be able to understand your code. In situations like these, it may also help you find the issue. Other parts of code style are also important, but indentation is usually the biggest help.

Comment: @DerekF I thought the issue was as I mentioned in the answer but with your edit seems it was not :). Will wait to see what OP was actually trying to do.

Comment: @JayantDas Your answer could very well be correct. Like I said, I took some liberties in editing to make the code readable. Usually when I see someone explicitly write "trigger" and/or "class", it's an indication that they're meant to be two separate blocks of code. Looking at the original version of the question, it's very hard to figure out what exactly OP has or means.

Comment: @DerekF :) I actually mapped the braces to see where the class was actually written and then tried replicating it in my DE, got the same error, so that seemed to be the issue. My answer reflects what you have mentioned, trigger/class should be just separated out!

Comment: @DerekF I have rolled back the question to the version prior to your edit so that the answer maps to the issue as seen in the question. Hope it works.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to declare a class after the trigger body and that's why you are facing this compilation error.

Current form:

```
trigger ... {
 ...
}

public class abc { // you will get error here viz., Missing '<EOF>' at 'public'
 ...
}
```

While you can fix this with the approach below where you will need to include the class within the trigger

```
trigger ... {
    ...

    public class abc { // now defined within the trigger body
        ...
    }
}
```

**BUT you should not** be using this approach. It's always a good practice to keep the logic out of the trigger body. Your optimal trigger and class logic should look as below.

WHERE you create the apex class separately in a different file:

```
public class abc {
    public void myMethod() { ... }
}
```

AND then you utilize it in your trigger as:

```
trigger ... {
    ...
    abc a = new abc();
    a.myMethod();
    ...
}
```

I will recommend that you go through the below resources to get more on Apex Classes and Triggers:

- [Apex Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_understanding.htm)
- [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Trigger.htm)